# NameError: name '_length' is not defined

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I'm using python3 and when trying to run the following code, I'm facing the error:

```
NameError: name '_length' is not defined
```

The code itself:

```
class OFPHELLO(GenericStruct):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._length = self.get_size()

    _msg_type = OFPType.OFPT_HELLO
    _build_order = ('header', 'x')

    header = OFPHeader(type = _msg_type, length = _length)
    x = UBInt8()
```

The problem is the `_length` variable that I'm passing in `OFPHeader`, the value of which is computed in `GenericStruct`. How can I compute the `_length` variable inside the `OFPHELLO` class and use it as parameter in the `OFPHeader` class?

Following the `GenericStruct` code:

```
class GenericStruct(object):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      for a in kwargs:
          try:
              field = getattr(self, a)
              field.value = kwargs[a]
          except AttributeError:
              raise OFPException("Attribute error: %s" % a)

 def build(self):
      hexa = ""
      for field in self._build_order:
          hexa += getattr(self, field).build()
      return hexa

 def parse(self, buff):
      begin = 0
      for field in self._build_order:
          size = getattr(self, field).get_size()
          getattr(self,field).parse(buff, offset=begin)
          begin += size

 def get_size(self):
      tot = 0
      for field in self._build_order:
          tot += getattr(self, field).get_size()
      return tot
```

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of your exception? Where does `GenericStruct` come from?

Comment: Also note that you are misspelling `_length`, transposing the `t` and `h`.

Comment: I also fixed your post indentation. Please verify that it matches your actual code.

Comment: Is it perhaps because you've misspelled "length".  Switch the last two letters.

Answer (score 0):

**-** how have you defined **(GenericStruct)**
**-**  header = OFPHeader(type = _msg_type, length = _lenght)
       **-** correct the spelling to _length

**--** and please post the entire code next time

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sheikh, but the spelling error was done when I was posting the question, the code is ok. Im posting the entire code.